# Can't access data in JSON file beyond the third nesting level

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to extract a piece of data from [this JSON file](https://medium.com/curious-futures/latest/?format=json) in PHP, specifically `post -> virtuals -> previewImage -> imageId`. I can access anything up to the level of `previewImage`, but for some unknown reason I can't go beyond that:

```
$data = @file_get_contents("https://medium.com/".$publication_name."/latest?format=json");
$data = str_replace("])}while(1);</x>", "", $data);
$json = json_decode($data);
$posts = $json->payload->posts;
foreach($posts as $post) {
  echo $post->virtuals->previewImage->imageId;
  ...
```

...echoes nothing. I can get/echo `$post->virtuals->subtitle` for example. But anything inside `virtuals` returns nothing. Why on earth?

Screenshot of the payload:

[image]

Comment: How did you decode the JSON string in PHP? Have you tried using `json_decode($JSNstr,true)` to convert it into a structure of arrays and not objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'post' in there you need to address `JSONobj->payload->posts[0]->virtuals->previewImage->imageId` instead.

I have tried both versions of using json_decode:

```
$jsn2=json_decode($jsnstr);
echo $jsn2->payload->posts[0]->virtuals->previewImage->imageId."\n";
```

and

```
$jsn=json_decode($jsnstr,true);
echo $jsn['payload']['posts'][0]['virtuals']['previewImage']['imageId'];
```

Both return:

```
1*WMPzz4dBjNY7iPB0u2Y3Aw.png
```

Are you sure that you have got the full JSON string back from the server? Have you echo'ed it?

Answer (score 1):

https://eval.in/857307

```
$object->posts[0]->virtuals->previewImage->imageId;
```

variable "posts" is an array.

Comment: In my code that would be $json->posts[0]->virtuals->previewImage->imageId isn't it? (cause this is always empty)